# XMLstarlet filter and export

Tags: xmlstarlet

I need with xmlstarlet to filter the content of a XML and export elements based on subelement criteria

Using this kind of xml:

```
<products>
<product>
<product_code>1-70-032-0023</product_code>
<availability>criteria_i_need</availability>
<quantity>393</quantity>
</product>
<product>
<product_code>1-70-032-0024</product_code>
<availability>criteria_i_need</availability>
<quantity>19</quantity>
</product>
<product>
<product_code>1-70-032-0046</product_code>
<availability>criteria_i_do_NOT_need</availability>
<quantity>351</quantity>
</product>
</products>
```

using the command:

```
xmlstarlet ed -d '/product/availability[. = "criteria_i_need"]' input-file.xml > filtered-file.xml
```

but the output file contains ALL elements  and not only the 2 firsts that match the criteria.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what you expect `filtered-file.xml` to contain, but since you used `ed -d` as your argument, I assume you want to delete the one `<product>` that does **not** meet your criteria and save the rest.

So I would change your command to

```
xmlstarlet ed -d '//product[not(.//availability[. = "criteria_i_need"])]' input-file.xml > filtered-file.xml
```

and see if it works.

Alternatively you could delete on a specfiic criteria, e.g.:

```
xmlstarlet ed -d 'products/product[availability = "criteria_i_do_NOT_need"]'
```

or with `contains()`:

```
xmlstarlet ed -d 'products/product[contains(availability, "_NOT_")]'
```

Comment: It worked absolutely great. I tried to syntax it so i keep the elements <product> that match my criteria but your command erasing the opposite has the same result.